# I can't able to find html video file in google analytics landing page. why?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, landing-page

I can't able to find html video file in google analytics landing page. The has mp4 file. we need to implement anything? please give me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

These views can be found under

Google Analytics > Content > Events > Top Events > Video / Seconds played.

Play around with the 'Secondary dimension' dropdown. For a better visual view select the pie chart. If your site already uses or is planning to use Google Analytics it's good to view those statistics in the same place.

Comment: Google Analytics -> Acquisition ->  Search Engine Optimization -> Landing Page

in this section i can't able to find the html video page..( file is embedded with .mp4 format)